# Twisted FTP server does not show files after login

Tags: python, ftp, twisted

I'm running `twistd -n ftp --root=/tmp --password-file=/tmp/pass.dat`

I can connect with `ftp ftp://localhost:2121` and run `ls`. However if I login, and try the same `ls` then I get the following error:

```
550 []: No such file or directory.
```

Any ideas?

Thanks, Miki

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem until I found this in bugtracer: http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/4494
This code

```
avatar = FTPShell(filepath.FilePath("/home/" + avatarId))
```

means that your FTP login should be the same as your Linux login, so that "/home/login" directory would exist.